# Error when running TMUX under CYGWIN

Tags: tmux, cygwin

When I run `tmux` in cygwin command line I get the error:

```
$ tmux
      0 [main] tmux 6688 C:\cygwin64\bin\tmux.exe: *** fatal error - NtCreateEvent(lock): 0xC0000077
Hangup
```

I tried to reinstall tmux 1.9a-1 using cygwin setup, also installed tmux-debuginfo but to no avail.
**My os**: Windows 7 x64
**uname -a**: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Heaven 1.7.32(0.274/5/3) 2014-08-13 23:06 x86_64 Cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question appeared closely related to [another one previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604510/encounter-fatal-error-ntcreateeventlock-0xc0000077-when-execute-kinit-in), which hinted at the possible **culprit**: the 64-bit version of Cygwin.

Indeed it has helped a countless number of users to install the **32bit version of Cygwin**, which - in most of cases - made `tmux` and other applications work.

Oddly enough, a sort of "derivative" of this bug was reported back in 2011 already: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/128288 .

Nevertheless, this IS a **bug** and must be properly fixed in the 64-bit version of Cygwin. I hope for all users this will have happened by the end of the new year.

Answer (score 0):

A different cause of the same problem can also occur.

`.babun\cygwin\bin\tmux.exe: *** fatal error - NtCreateEvent(lock): 0xC0000058`

Your anti-virus might stop the program from running.

The solution is to exclude the program from being blocked. 
(With bitdefender its Show->modules->Anti Virus->Exclusions->Excluded Processes )